# An old Logitech MX Master 2S's gesture button is mapped to alt+ctrl+tab: how?

Tags: mouse, automation

Using either KeyCastr or Karabiner Events Viewer, I can see that my Logitech MX Master 2S's "gesture button" invokes a <kbd>⌃⌥⇥</kbd>.

Surely this is something past me has done to present me for some reason, but I cannot remember what it was — nor how I set it up.

I have looked through all the macro, automation, and UI input modification tools I can think of and have not found anything that remaps the button to those keys.

Is there anything I can do to investigate this further?

My next step is to see if the mouse behaves the same way on other devices, which I suppose would indicate that it has somehow been remapped on a firmware level...

Comment: Okay, I tested it on an iMac that is basically a stock machine using KeyCastr... and it still triggers the keystrokes. I am completely befuddled by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mappings are stored on device. You need the [Logitech Options](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/software/logi-options-plus.html) software to configure it.

Comment: This was right. Never imagined that these settings would save to the mouse. I'd uninstalled the various Logitech apps because they are a bit bloated these days — reinstalling and resetting this configuration worked. Thanks!